# how can I protect the private data on my Iphone?

Tags: security, iphone, ios

what is the best way to secure data on my iphone?

In my opinion I have to protect myself against the following risks:

- theft
- fault and phone must be returned

I fear for the following data

- Logins to email, dorpbox, calender, ...
- mails, photos, chat history, ...

The phone is allways locked, but with hardware access it might be possible to read the data...

Comment: The number one rule: don't put your sensitive data on it in the first place. My phone has a few phone numbers and that's it. No mail, no sensitive documents, no passwords, etc. I even avoid the various stores so I don't have to enter a password that's automagically saved. I do store downloads on a laptop or MacBook and then transfer to the device.

Comment: agreed but that's not an easy choice to make, not always.

Answer (score 1):

Take the following steps as there is no one sure shot way to get the protection that will actually protect you (at-least to some extent):

1. **Enable data Encryption** on your device, even if someone is able to gain access to your data on the phone memory, there will be a layer of protection.
2. **Apple/Google provide web management** device utilities which gives ability for remote locking, remotely wiping data, changing passwords etc, check out those settings. Some third-party app provide for this as well.
3. don't install apps from outside the app store.
4. **setup secure passwords and locks** (**use numbers lower-case, upper-case, symbols** etc, you may even **use special characters** that are not directly available on the keyboard)
5. **change your passwords often,** maybe every 6 months atleast.
6. **Enable 2-step authentication.** *PROBABLY ONE OF THE BEST THING YOU COULD DO RIGHT NOW.* Most leading service providers, DropBox, Gmail (and other google services), Evernote provide this
   option. then you need two bits of information to access your
   account:

   - one, the information you know, your password.
   - second, the information you get (through an SMS/Email).
7. **Provide an option for recovery,** such as secondary mail/ contact number in case you forget your password.
8. keep a track of security holes such as the recent Heartbleed bug.
9. when some one uses your phone to make a call/text, be close and it might be a good idea to take his/her picture (you don't know whome he/she might be calling to, maybe some terrorist?)
10. you may even want to **subscribe for sms updates** for your
     facebook, twitter and google+  etc notifications for any suspicious
     activities in real time.

Comment: "Enable data Encryption" - not very helpful when folks like Apple provides no protection over important passwords and other secrets (i.e., `￼kSecAttrAccessible=all`, which means its always available - even without a login). The passwords include VPN, LDAP, and email password. See, for example, [iOS Keychain Weakness FAQ](https://www.sit.fraunhofer.de/fileadmin/dokumente/sonstiges/iPhone_keychain_faq.pdf).

Comment: Then such people better not use apple. ;-)

Comment: Yeah, its not just Apple - its all of them. Don't fall into the trap of thinking a mobile device or tablet is like a laptop with full disk encryption ;)

Comment: is data Encryption on Iphone enabled with Passcode or is it necessary to enabled "Erase Data" -> below this setting the iphone shows text that "data protection is enabled"?

Answer (score 0):

so after googeling around based on the suggestions above, I am faced with the following situation:

Parts of my data are encrpyted by default with apple passcode but most of it is not encrypted:

- fotos
- chat history form skype, facebook
- E-Mail and SMS

A small possibility is to remote wipe the phone, if it has not previously jailbreaked or opened...